# Is there a PPA or other repository for recent proprietary ATI drivers?

Tags: ati, ppa, repository, fglrx, proprietary

I was happy to find the [X Updates PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) as it has made installing newer nVidia drivers much easier. Without using the PPA, I found that the driver installed using the restricted drivers GUI often 'killed' systems with newer nVidia cards. Now it's just a matter of adding the X Updates PPA, updating installed packages *then* installing the restricted nVidia driver.

Unfortunately it looks like the fglrx-installer in the X-Updates PPA is nearly a year old and I'm a bit leary of using it on newer AMD gear like the Fusion APUs. Is there a repo I can add to easily install those drivers as well? The command line package building is a bit tedious and if there's a PPA that would make the Restricted Driver GUI usable for most ATI & nVidia hardware and it make things much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't locate a PPA for proprietary drivers, but this PPA for updated open source drivers seems to work better than the stock drivers for me:

Updated and Optimized Graphics Drivers
https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/

Answer (score 1):

On my system in 'Additional Drivers' (`jockey-gtk`), I can choose between:

- NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version current) [Recommended]
- NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (version current-updates)

Check if you have any ATI accelerated graphics driver that says '(post-release updates) (version current-updates)'.

Comment: I don't have it in front of me (it's another person's machine) but there's just one ATI restricted drive option and if we attempt to using it there is an error after downloading:

**SystemError: installArchives () failed**

This is on maverick x86 btw.